# Generate numbers separated with comma

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how I can generate x numbers separated with comma with a max limit defined in a variable ($total_days_month).

```
<?php
$total_days_month = date('t'); // get total days of this month

// generate numbers separated with comma from 1 until $total_days_month

?>
```

Comment: You could try with `for`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo implode(',', range(1, $total_days_month));
```